# SaveAstable with append Mode returning Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a metastore setup, and trying to add data from a dataset to same table using following code:

```java
String warehouseLocation = "file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + sessionName;
   session = SparkSession.builder().appName(sessionName).config(sparkConf)
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                    .getOrCreate(); 
dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).option("path", tablePathName).saveAsTable(tableName);
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
com.spectramd.products.focus.common.FocusException: 
Error Table Information : The location of the existing table `default`.`tablename` is 
`file:/D:/Spectramd/priya/Projects/Integrated/Platform/v1165/etl/SparkETL/spark-warehouse/MU2_2022/Stroke2/tablename`. 
It doesn't match the specified location `MU2_2022/Stroke2/tablename`.
```

It only throws this error when the table exists. How to resolve this?

Comment: missing prefit looks like

Comment: @thebluephantom, could you please explain. We did try adding prefix but it didn't help